# columnrange with stacked series

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to have a columrange chart with stacked series?

I've tried this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BnnCt/)  - but if i turn on the stacking option the chart does not display.

```
columnrange : {
    stacking: 'normal'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable stackign and set grouping as false. 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.columnrange.grouping

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BnnCt/1/

```
 plotOptions: {
        columnrange: {
            grouping:false
        }
    },
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks Sebastian - i tried many options but not that one!